Problem when converting pdf to image with the two versions of ghostscript 9.54 and 10.03
I am currently using ghostscript 9.54 and I got a problem when converting pdf to image with the parameters as followings

""
-dNOPAUSE
-dBATCH
-dSAFER
-sDEVICE=jpeggray
-r200
-dJPEGQ=100
-dAntiAliasGrayImage=false
-dAntiAliasMonoImage=false
-dAutoFilterColorImages=false
-dAutoFilterGrayImages=false
-dDownsampleColorImages=false
-dDownsampleGrayImages=false
-dDownsampleMonoImages=false
-dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged
-dConvertCMYKImagesToRGB=false
-dConvertImagesToIndexed=false
-dPreserveHalftoneInfo=true
18.-dPreserveOPIComments=true
-dCompatibilityLevel=1.7

The problem is the euro symbol in a text becomes a B after conversion.
This problem can be fixed with 10.03 with the same parameters. However, with the version 10.03, I got another problem when converting a text in this case.
enter image description here
I would like to know if I can change some parameters or fontmap... to fix this problem. Thanks

Can't say anything certain without seeing the PDF file, but the most likely problem is a font not embedded in the file. Almost all the parameters you give are incorrect. There are no parameters in Ghostscript which begin with 'GS_'. If you report a bug, as K J suggests, you should try to use the minimum command line required to demonstrate hte problem.

Thank @KenS, I just edited my parameters because I mistakenly posted the macro value. The commands works with 99% pdf but only 1 pdf with euro symbol character does not work. I thought of font problems too but I have not figured how to replace the fonts. When I opened the pdf by notepad++, I saw each page or paragraph has been embedded by different fonts.

@KJ thanks for suggesting. I will raise a report at GS bugzilla. The problem is I cannot give the pdf because it is confidential to our client. I just want to know if we can change the parameters above to have a better result.

If you can't supply the PDF file, then we aren't going to be able to help. There's no way we can tell you what the problem is, or if it can be addressed, without the original PDF. Pictures of the problem don't help.
